# how to implement segue from uitableviewcell to another tableviewcell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have two view controller with tableviewcell and in both of them I can add items.

What I want to implement is that when I add items in the first tableviewcell lets say I add (item one , item two) and press on (item one).

I want to sugue to the second tableviewcell and add data.

BUT I want the data in the second tableviewcell to save separately,

that means, now if I press on (item one) I should see the data that I added
 but if I press on (item two) it should be empty and I can add data later.

I have saved the data for the two tableviewcell in coredata.

Comment: Show your code first

Answer (score 0):

I don't use segues or coredata in this solution, but the solution will fix what you need to some extent at least.

```
class vc1: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let tableView = UITableView()
    let options: [Int] = [1,2]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return options.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = vc2()

        //Not sure where to put the setup to be honest
        //option 1:
        vc.setupTableView(forCell: indexPath.item)
        present(vc, animated: true) {
            //option 2:
            vc.setupTableView(forCell: indexPath.item)
        }
    }
}

class vc2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let tableView = UITableView()
    var selectedCell: Int!
    //Having an nested array in an array will solve this custom "page" you are looking for
    let results: [[String]] = [["test1", "test2"], ["test3", "test4"]]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func setupTableView(forCell cell: Int) {
        selectedCell = cell
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return results[selectedCell].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel = results[selectedCell][indexPath.item]
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```